# Algorithm to outline a group of points

Tags: algorithms, graphics

I have a set of coordinates, in practice gps coordinates. 
Some of them are in clusters and some of them are scattered. Which are which is allready determined. Thus I know which ones are in a particular group and which are not.

The ones in a cluster I want to graphically mark as a group by drawing an outline around them similar to this image.

[image]

Is this a problem that can be solved by any well know algorithm?

Comment: Use the convex hull, maybe adding some padding?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your question properly. Just draw a circle around each point in the group and take the union of the area. Most image libraries should have algorithms for this.

Comment: That last suggestion seems like a good one. I will try that and get back.

Comment: In pratice you can use it:http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/classify2d.html

Comment: @Hjulle If the cluster has "gaps" with your chosen radius, you'd still have/want to compute the convex hull? That said, make an answer, maybe with a specific example?

Comment: @Raphael Not necessarily, but you should probably fill the holes anyways. With convex hull banana shaped clusters would cover an unnecessarily large area. (On the other hand, if you don't have any large "banana clusters", it doesn't hurt.) But the hand drawn examples are clearly not convex.

Comment: @Hjulle True enough. Identifying "fillable" gaps may leave a somewhat interesting task.